# How does PHP use the JsonSerializable interface?

Tags: php

I'm confused with how `JsonSerializable` works. Let me elaborate bit more the question. Normally we use interfaces like this:

```php
interface Countable {
    /* Methods */
    public function count();    
}

class MyThings implements Countable 
{
    public function count() {
        return count($this->arrayOfThings);
    }
}


$obj = new MyThings();

$obj->count();
```

So we have a class and it implements the interface. When we call `count()` method, it is already written in `MyThings` class. It is simple to understand.

But when we use `JsonSerializable` interface like this:

```php
class Thing implements JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        // do something 
    }
}
$obj = new Thing();

json_encode($obj);
```

`jsonSerialize()` inside `Thing` runs with the `json_encode()` call. It is understandable if we call:

```php
$obj->jsonSerialize();
```

then there is a function called `jsonSerialize()` inside the class. But, how does this work when we run `json_encode()`? How this is constructed in php? Can someone explain what type of patterns are used here?

Answer (score 13):

Objects that `implement` [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) then implement a [jsonSerialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) method. Then, when [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is serializing its input into JSON, if a value that it is serializing is a `JsonSerializable`, it calls the `jsonSerialize()` method, and the *result* of that method is used as the object's serialized representation.

For example, from the PHP documentation:

> ```
> <?php
> class IntegerValue implements JsonSerializable {
>     public function __construct($number) {
>         $this->number = (integer) $number;
>     }
>
>     public function jsonSerialize() {
>         return $this->number;
>     }
> }
>
> echo json_encode(new IntegerValue(1), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
> ```

will output

```
1
```

which is the `json_encode`d value representing the number 1. The PHP documentation gives three more examples like this, returning values from the object, but since `jsonSerialize()` allows you to specify the actual data to be returned, it is important to realize that it can return *anything*. For example:

```
class JsonSerializeExample implements JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'boolean' => true,
            'random_integer' => rand(),
            'int_from_object' => new IntegerValue(42),
            'another_object' => new stdClass,
        ];
    }
}
$obj = new JsonSerializeExample();
echo json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Will output

```
{
    "boolean": true,
    "random_integer": 1140562437,
    "int_from_object": 42,
    "another_object": {}
}
```

Of note is that `random_integer` is not a static value stored anywhere; it changes on each execution; and `int_from_object` demonstrates that `json_encode()` will recursively evaluate `JsonSerializable` instances.

Comment: But how does the `jsonSerialize` method ever run? What magic is happening in the background?

Comment: @SeventhSteel It's not really magic. The internal implementation of `json_encode()` is written to call `jsonSerialize()` when trying to serialize an object that `implements JsonSerializable`, instead of taking the action it would normally take for serializing an object.

Answer (score 1):

get_object_vars its a good pratice.

Some example:

```
<?php
class Usuario implements JsonSerializable{
    // your code
    public function jsonSerialize():mixed{
        return get_object_vars($this);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).