# class attribute visibility for api in php

Tags: php, api

I have class Task with private attribute with some getters / setters

```
class Task
{
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $done;
    private $user_id;
    private $parent_id;


    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setId($id): Task
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $title
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setTitle($title):Task
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDone(): bool
    {
        return $this->done;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $done
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setDone($done):Task
    {
        $this->done = $done;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserId(): string
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $done
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setUserId($user_id):Task
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getParentId(): string
    {
        return $this->parent_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $done
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setParentId($parent_id):Task
    {
        $this->parent_id = $parent_id;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

And I wanted to put in public all thoses attributes ( I am try to make an api )
Here the usage of this class for example

```
    public function index()
    {
        $taskManager = new TaskManager();

        $tasks = $taskManager->selectWhere('parent_id IS NULL');

        foreach ($tasks as $key => $task){

            $taskId = $task->getId();
            $subtask = $taskManager->selectWhere("parent_id = $taskId");
            $tasks[$key]->subtasks = $subtask;

        }

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($tasks);
        echo '</pre>';

        
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 Created');
        header('Content-Type:application/json');
        return json_encode($tasks->getDataForApi());
        

    }
```

I am using postman to test my api and if i put all attribute in public in works but i don't think it is a good way to do this
Should I put all thoses attribute in public in my class Task ? or is there an other solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does PHP use the JsonSerializable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218131/how-does-php-use-the-jsonserializable-interface)

Comment: @WesleySmith hmm my problem is to change private to public for my attributes

Comment: That's the thing though, if your class implements the `JsonSerializable` interface and provides a `jsonSerialize` method, you can completely control what properties are included in the JSON representation of the class _without_ having to change anything about your private properties.

Comment: If you were to do the above, you could simply call `json_encode($tasks);` and PHP will automagically call your class's `jsonSerialize` method for each class object in the set where you can return exactly what you need to from your class including any private property values because it is called from the context of the class itself which has access to all those things